# What's the behavior of iOS smart app links in webviews?

Tags: ios6, uiwebview

We link to our own website from within our app, displaying some pages in a webview.

If a smart app link is configured, will it still show up? And if so, how to stop it doing so (as it only makes sense to show up if someone is simply web browsing)?

Answer (score 1):

Smart banners don't appear in browsers other than Mobile Safari, including web views - they are essentially a Safari-specific feature.

Some developers have implemented features that look like smart banners for use in other browsers (for example, http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/01/ios-smart-app-banners-in-browsers-not-named-safari/), but that doesn't sound like what you want.